# Set value of input text field inside jquery.on

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery.on on input buttons to identify which button was pressed. I want to set the value of a text field with a value from one of the attributes on the input button pressed.

The jquery

```
$('input.btne').on('click', function () {
    var btn = $(":input[type=button]:focus");
    var amount = btn.attr("amount"); 
    $("#fee_amount").val(amount);
});
```

The html

```
<input type="text" id="fee_amount" />
<input type="button" id="idF" class="btne" optionText="My option Text" amount="123.00" value="Edit" />
```

I tried doing this but it said undefined
    alert($("#fee_amount").val());

The amount is correct and present but it will not go into the fee_amount field. Can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave wrong id in selector `txt_feeamount` should be `fee_amount` as the input you have has id `fee_amount` not `txt_feeamount`

Note you can get the source of event using `$(this)` or `this` instead of  `var btn = $(":input[type=button]:focus");` Here :focus does not make any sense as well.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vr9xq/1/)**

```
$('input.btne').on('click', function () {
    $("#fee_amount").val($(this).attr('amount'));
});
```

Defining attribute like you have amount is not good practice. You should use **[data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)**. The amount attribute will be data-amount.

**Using data- to define data attributes**

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vr9xq/3/)**

*Html*

```
<input type="text" id="fee_amount" />
<input type="button" id="idF" class="btne" optionText="My option Text" data-amount="123.00" value="Edit" />
```

Javascript

```
$('input.btne').on('click', function () {
    $("#fee_amount").val($(this).data('amount'));
});
```

Comment: Actually it is `#fee_amount`.

Comment: Thanks @Padarom, so nice of you

Comment: Thank you for noticing my obvious error! Still not working though, I have updated code above.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I wasn't aware of data attributes, so thanks for the link also.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use custom attributes such as `amount` to convey data; it's better to use data attributes for that:

```
<input type="text" id="fee_amount" />
<input type="button" id="idF" class="btne" data-amount="123.00" value="Edit" />
```

Secondly, to get the current button being clicked you can simply reference `this`.

Lastly, you were using the wrong selector for the text box outlet; `#fee_amount` vs `#txt_feeamount`.

Then the code becomes:

```
$('.btne').on('click', function() {
    $('#fee_amount').val($(this).data('amount'));
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/pavizupo/1/watch?html,js,output)